firebase error after updating to manifest version 3 in chrome extension
Changed the manifest.json file version to 3 from 2 and the email login using firebase started to break showing the below errors I tried to add path of firebase-app.js, firebase-auth.js and  firebase-firestore.js I downloaded all the this file in my project directory and menstioned the path in index.html

Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.1/firebase-app.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.


index.html:86  Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.1/firebase-app.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' in localhost". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.


index.html:89  Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.1/firebase-auth.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.


index.html:89  Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.1/firebase-auth.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' in localhost". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.


index.html:89  Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.1/firebase-firestore.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.


index.html:89  Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.1/firebase-firestore.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules in localhost Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

these are the  and manifest.json file
{
  "name" : "extension firebase login",
"content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches":["<all_urls>"],
        "js":["script.js"],
        "run_at":"document_end"
    }
],
"type": "module",
"action": {
    "default_title": "FirebaseExt",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
},
"background":{
    "service-worker":"firebase.js"
}
}


